# How to diagnose crash on Linux kernel version 5.10.92 aarch64 (Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4)

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, crash, arm64

### Reproduction

We've built a crash reproduction application that does nothing but allocate memory and append to log files.  The process allocates 4GB (in small blocks) and writes to them in a loop, which loop also append-logs to a file. (fills up 4GB RAM, 400MB of which is allocated to the GPU, and takes about 500M of the 2GB swap).  We've also been experiencing this when allocating less than the swap, and without the swap altogether.  Having the large allocation into the swap just seems to speed up the crash, which suggests to us something IO related.

### Symptom

We see the following in the TTY serial terminal attached:

```
[  926.386714] rcu: INFO: rcu_preempt self-detected stall on CPU
[  926.392580] rcu:     0-....: (5249 ticks this GP) idle=6be/1/0x4000000000000002 softirq=29651/29651 fqs=2625
[  926.402388]  (t=5250 jiffies g=61417 q=108)
[  926.406637] Task dump for CPU 0:
[  926.409914] task:kswapd0         state:R  running task     stack:    0 pid:  69 ppid:     2 flags:0x0000002a
[  926.419997] Call trace:
[  926.422497]  dump_backtrace+0x0/0x1c0
[  926.426219]  show_stack+0x24/0x30
[  926.429591]  sched_show_task+0x154/0x180
[  926.433579]  dump_cpu_task+0x50/0x60
[  926.437210]  rcu_dump_cpu_stacks+0xb8/0xf8
[  926.441371]  rcu_sched_clock_irq+0x9b4/0xed0
[  926.445710]  update_process_times+0x6c/0xe0
[  926.449961]  tick_sched_handle+0x3c/0x60
[  926.453946]  tick_sched_timer+0x84/0x110
[  926.457931]  __hrtimer_run_queues+0x15c/0x410
[  926.462356]  hrtimer_interrupt+0x100/0x2d0
[  926.466517]  arch_timer_handler_phys+0x40/0x50
[  926.471032]  handle_percpu_devid_irq+0xb0/0x2b0
[  926.475631]  __handle_domain_irq+0xbc/0x140
[  926.479879]  gic_handle_irq+0x5c/0xf0
[  926.483598]  el1_irq+0xcc/0x180
[  926.486791]  check_preemption_disabled+0x2c/0x110
[  926.491571]  debug_smp_processor_id+0x24/0x30
[  926.495996]  scan_swap_map_try_ssd_cluster+0xa8/0x1f0
[  926.501126]  scan_swap_map_slots+0x74/0x760
[  926.505374]  get_swap_pages+0x174/0x280
[  926.509268]  get_swap_page+0xc4/0x230
[  926.512989]  add_to_swap+0x24/0xa0
[  926.516445]  shrink_page_list+0xa28/0xc30
[  926.520515]  shrink_inactive_list+0x174/0x460
[  926.524940]  shrink_lruvec+0x3b8/0x5e0
[  926.528746]  shrink_node+0x390/0x6f0
[  926.532377]  balance_pgdat+0x288/0x660
[  926.536184]  kswapd+0x210/0x560
[  926.539374]  kthread+0x14c/0x160
[  926.542652]  ret_from_fork+0x10/0x38
```

There is nothing interesting logged in journalctl, it shows logged entries then simply ends.  Once crashed, there no network responsivity or any other signs of life besides the `rcu: INFO: rcu_preempt self-detected stall on CPU` message periodically repeated on the serial terminal.  We've enabled coredumpctl and we don't seem to get a dump.

### Diagnostic attempts

- We've tried on our custom Buildroot OS, as well as on Raspberry Pi OS.
- We've tried this on multiple devices with the same result.
- We tried a different SD card brand.
- We tried removing the secondary SD card overlay (sd2-wifi) and the wifi overlay too – with these not removed, we saw this before the above crash dump:

```
[  911.006842] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_bus_rxctl: resumed on timeout
[  911.013511] ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_cfg80211_dump_station: BRCMF_C_GET_ASSOCLIST unsupported, err=-110
```

We're not kernel developers and we're at a loss on how to diagnose this.  We found [this thread](https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/fcf95129-cba7-817d-4bfd-8efaf92f957f@gmail.com/), which seems to relate to the same driver and same error on an earlier kernel, but since we removed the wifi and secondary SD overlays, it seems like something else.  Any ideas of things we can try to at least determine the cause?

Comment: Just a follow up.  We increased the OS partition size and moved the swap file onto that same partition and we haven't yet seen the problem.